# Por que o seguinte código não funciona?

Tags: python, array, algoritmo, lista

O código deve receber uma quantidade de notas de alunos, imprimir a média das notas e quantas notas estão 10% abaixo e 10% acima da média. O código está assim:

```
quantidade = int(raw_input())
inicio = 0
ListaDeNotas = list()
while quantidade > inicio:
    notas = int(raw_input())
    inicio = inicio + 1
    ListaDeNotas.append(notas)
MediaDasNotas = sum(ListaDeNotas) / len(ListaDeNotas)
print ("%.2f" % MediaDasNotas)
Notas10Acima = list()
Notas10Abaixo = list()
for nota in ListaDeNotas:
    if nota > ((0.1 * MediaDasNotas) + MediaDasNotas): 
        Notas10Acima.append(nota)
    elif nota < (MediaDasNotas - (0.1 * MediaDasNotas)):
        Notas10Abaixo.append(nota)
print len(Notas10Acima)
print len(Notas10Abaixo)
```

Exemplo de como deveria funcionar:
Entrada:

```
5
23
12
45
24
28
```

Saída:

```
26.40
1
2
```

Meu código deveria imprimir a média `26.40`, para esses valores, mas imprime `26.00`. Onde estou errando?

Comment: Por que os votos negativos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema trocando `int()` por `float()` na linha 5. Código:

```
quantidade = int(raw_input())
inicio = 0
ListaDeNotas = list()
while quantidade > inicio:
    notas = float(raw_input())
    inicio = inicio + 1
    ListaDeNotas.append(notas)
MediaDasNotas = sum(ListaDeNotas) / len(ListaDeNotas)
print ("%.2f" % MediaDasNotas)
Notas10Acima = list()
Notas10Abaixo = list()
for nota in ListaDeNotas:
    if nota > ((0.1 * MediaDasNotas) + MediaDasNotas): 
        Notas10Acima.append(nota)
    elif nota < (MediaDasNotas - (0.1 * MediaDasNotas)):
        Notas10Abaixo.append(nota)
print len(Notas10Acima)
print len(Notas10Abaixo)
```